# Android create favourites issue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hi I need a little help with an issue that I have.

I had to build an application which needs to show only a text information and pictures.The content was a lot, that's why instead of creating 200 single activities for very page I create one base activity which content I'm changing everytime depends on which listview item is clicked using `putExtra();` and `getExtra();`. So the problem now is that they want me to create Favourites page, where the users can save some of the information and access them on a single activity.Actually it's really easy to do this using sqlite,but they want from me to finish the application today, within a few hours.My problem is that If i start coding it again and insert all that information in database it will take much more time for me.

So here is a little more explanation :

1.I have base activity with a listview.

2.When user click on listview item I send the content using putExtra in base activity.

So I need to learn how to save the id of listview item or something else and show that content in new Activity. I was thinking of using SharedPreferences but not really sure how to deal with that.

Any suggestions how I can do that...for a few hours.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dont worry every deadline is last date until product is finally published :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with sharedpreferences too,but it's not a good idea.
The best way is to do it with database,but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of content is it? Is it over 200 entries and you don't save them locally?

Just knowing if it's a favorite or not can not be more than one hour job using sqlite. Just keep the id of the content and then a value to see if it's a favorite or not.

Noone will really do that for you since it's obviously your (paid?) job. The fact that you can't do it in time is really not a reason to skip the best option to use. 
I would say don't be that optimistic about what you can achieve in which time. Manage your resources better and you will not have that problem.

Comment: Actually I'm not really good in sqlite and that's why it will take a little more for me.And it's not a paid job, the application is for a friend of mine and his company.He just want me to show a text content and image in every single activity.